# Add class Remove class via jQuery...what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an application that allows users to pick specific fonts for a textarea.  Some fonts need to have different line-height attributes.  I'm trying to make the line-height dependent on what font they clicked on.  I can add the class 'larger-line' when they click on the id="larger-line", but I can't get it to remove the class when they click on 'standard-line'.  I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple.  Any thoughts?  Also...I'm pretty new to coding.

HTML:

```
<textarea>        
   <div class="editable" id="standard-line">"Font A"</div>
   <div class="editable" id="larger-line">"Font B"</div>
</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea.editable {
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
textarea.editable.larger-line {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#larger-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").addClass('larger-line'); 
});
$("#standard-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").removeClass('larger-line');
});
```

Comment: Text in a `<textarea>` element is just that, text, not DOM nodes. And that's not CSS you posted.

Comment: Also your `editable` class is set on the div, not the textarea. The divs are inside the textarea which would make this selector `textatrea .editable` note the space. But yeah like pointed out `textarea` are for text only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#larger-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").addClass('larger-line'); 
});
$("#standard-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").removeClass('larger-line');
});
```

That code would match the following elements.

```
<textarea class="editable></textarea>
```

First off your code wont work because your putting html inside of a textarea. That converts the html into plaintext.

Look in this jsfiddle:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acaj5ofr/)

The following JS Code:

```
$("#larger-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").addClass('larger-line'); 
});
$("#standard-line").on("click", function (e) {
   $("textarea.editable").removeClass('larger-line');
});
```

The following markup:

```
<div id="standard-line">"Font A"</div>
<div id="larger-line">"Font B"</div>
<textarea class="editable"></textarea>
```

When you click on "Font A" or "Font B" it will add or remove the class "larger-line" from the textarea with class "editable"

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You used `"textarea.editable"` which selects all textarea elements with the class editable. What I think you wanted to do was `"textarea .editable"` which selects all elements with the class editable inside of a textarea. However, textareas are meant to only contain text, so you'll get the html as text as output and it won't be selectable.